# How to programmatically send message to webview about error

Tags: android

I have webView on activity.
How can I send message about error to this webView in order to load error web page?

Comment: why can't you Just implement onReceivedError to handle errors

Comment: please explain your question. according to my understanding  send custom error code using Intent on basis of error code show error web page

Comment: onReceivedError - this is callback. I need to send message, not receive

Answer (score 1):

I assume there was an error on the website that was loaded, and you want to communicate this to the app.

You can use [Javascript binding](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript) for this.

If you meant the other way around: there is an error in the app and you want to show an error page, you can simply load a different url using `webView.loadUrl(...)`

Answer (score 1):

please explain your question in detail. according to my understanding send custom error code using Intent on basis of error code show error web page.

```
     WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
         wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);                    
Log.i("WEB_VIEW_TEST", "error code:" + errorCode);
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myerrorpage.html");

            }
         });
```